# Maven eclipse plugin error Lorg/sonatype/plexus/build/incremental/BuildContext;

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin

Can someone let me know how to fix the same?.I tried to create a new maven project and it fails for some reason

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources: Lorg/sonatype/plexus/build/incremental/BuildContext;

Answer (score 0):

Have updated the maven-resource-plugin to version 2.6. It works fine with M2Eclipse integration v1.3 milestone.

Answer (score -2):

My experience with eclipse and maven is not good I have been working for a long time with both and they don't integrate properly. The best way to make them work together for me was to use command line to build, package and install the projects and eclipse to edit.

To import the projects into eclipse I just use mvn eclipse:eclipse and it will generate the files needed to import the project into eclipse.